# Programming performance

Tags: windows

I would like to know if these 2 codes are the same for performance respecting the variable declarations:

```
int Value;
for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
{  Value = i;
}
```

or

```
for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
{  int Value = i;
}
```

Basically I need to know if the process time to create the variable Value and allocate it in Ram is just once in the first case and if it is, or not, repeated 1000 times in the second.

Comment: Which language? And what does it have to do with functional programming?

Comment: Well, I am thinking in C# and Java for Android. Actually I have no idea what tag to use. I thought this was for any kind of programming

Comment: Use the tag that is the name of the programming language you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are Programming in c++ or c#, there will be no runtime difference since no implicite initialization will be done for simple int type.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I wanted to know. What about if it is Android?

Comment: Android is java. I am not sure how integers are handled in JVM, there may be differences whether it is declared int or Integer.